# How to get Atomic Value between Element Nodes using XPath

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

I want to select only the atomic values inside a node. For example, the "here" text in the following:

```
<a href="">here</a>
```

When I use Xpath in Java, it returns some sort of object/array, such as

```
[DomNode[<a href="">here</a>]]
```

I just want the text only.

Is this possible, and how? Thanks!

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a correct XPath expression that selects the wanted text nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `text()` node test.  For example, if you want to select the text of all anchors with an href attribute you could do the following XPath query:

```
//*/a/@href/../text()
```

Comment: `text()` is not a function. It is a node test.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
//a[@href='']/text()
```

This selects all text nodes that are children of any `a` element in the document, that has an empty `href` attribute.